# How to implement two md-autocomplete of angular js material in single form and single controller in a web page?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, autocomplete, angularjs-material

I need two  md-autocomplete  in one page so according to angular js material document i include two md-autocomplete in my form,
ones for vehicle make  company name and other for  vehicle model but when i choose a vehicle name from first md-autocomplete then
second md-autocomplete appear  a    [object Object]  value. So  how i will modify its js function?

```
<!--Html Code-->
<md-autocomplete  required='' ng-disabled="isDisabled" md-no-cache="noCache" md-selected-item="selectedItem" md-search-text-change="searchTextChange(searchText)" md-search-text="searchTextModel" md-selected-item-change="selectedItemChange(item)" md-items="item in querySearch(searchTextModel)" md-item-text="item.name" md-min-length="0" md-menu-class="autocomplete-custom-template"  md-floating-label="Make">
    <md-item-template>
        <span class="item-title">
        <md-icon md-svg-icon="img/icons/octicon-repo.svg"></md-icon>
        <span>{{item.name}}</span>
        </span>
    </md-item-template>
    <div ng-messages="userForm.autocomplete.$error">
        <div ng-message="required">This field is required</div>
    </div>
</md-autocomplete>


<md-autocomplete  required='' ng-disabled="isDisabled" md-no-cache="noCache" md-selected-item="selectedItemModel" md-search-text-change="searchTextChange(searchText)" md-search-text="searchText"  md-items="item in querySearchModel(searchText)" md-item-text="item.title" md-min-length="0" md-menu-class="autocomplete-custom-template"  md-floating-label="Model">
    <md-item-template>
        <span class="item-title">
        <span> {{item.name}} </span>
        </span>
    </md-item-template>
    <div ng-messages="userForm.autocomplete.$error">
        <div ng-message="required">This field is required</div>
    </div>
</md-autocomplete>




 //Angular js Controller code

  //Auto complete function for car make

  $scope.make=[{id:1,name:"Audi"},{id:2,name:"BMW"},{id:3,name:"Ferrari"}];
  $scope.selectedItem  = null;
  $scope.searchText    = null;
  $scope.querySearch   = querySearch;


   function querySearch (query) {

          var results = query ? $scope.categories.filter(createFilterFor(query)) : $scope.make,
                        deferred;
                    if (self.simulateQuery) {
                        deferred = $q.defer();
                        $timeout(function () {
                            deferred.resolve(results);
                        }, Math.random() * 1000, false);
                        return deferred.promise;
                    } else {
                        return results;
                    }

   }

   function createFilterFor(query) {
      var lowercaseQuery = angular.lowercase(query);

      return function filterFn(Make) {
        //alert(state);
        //console.log(state);
        return (Make.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(lowercaseQuery) === 0);
      };

    }


   //Auto complete function for car models
   $scope.model=[{mid:1,id:1,name:"Q3"},{mid:2,id:1,name:"Q6"},{mid:3,id:1,name:"Q2"}];
   $scope.selectedItemModel  = null;
   $scope.searchTextModel    = null;
   $scope.querySearchModel=querySearchModel;


   function querySearchModel (query) {

          var results = query ? $scope.model.filter(createFilterFor(query)) : $scope.model,
                        deferred;
                    if (self.simulateQuery) {
                        deferred = $q.defer();
                        $timeout(function () {
                            deferred.resolve(results);
                        }, Math.random() * 1000, false);
                        return deferred.promise;
                    } else {
                        return results;
                    }

   }


   function createFilterForModel(query) {
      var lowercaseQuery = angular.lowercase(query);

      return function filterFn(Model) {
       return (Model.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(lowercaseQuery) === 0);
      };

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I also had a similar issue and found your question. On the first autocomplete you call `searchTextChange(searchText)`, but `searchText` is from the second autocomplete, while in the first you called it `searchTextModel`.

---

I found this because I had a problem on which multiple autocomplete on the same page where sharing the value. Your question help me found a solution. While in Bootstrap's typeahead you use `$viewValue` for any typeahead, on `mdAutocomplete` you specify which model to bind the searchText, and thus, you cannot use the same binding on all autocompletes, you have to have one for each.